# MySQL if statement in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
| id | msgType | user | job_id | project_id |
|+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|
| 1  | 1       | 1    | 1      | 1          |
| 2  | 1       | 1    | 2      | 1          |
| 3  | 2       | 1    | 3      | 1          |
| 4  | 2       | 1    | 4      | 1          |
| 5  | 1       | 1    | 5      | 2          |
```

This my query:

```
SELECT msgType ,user, job_id, project_id 
FROM mail
GROUP BY msgType,user,project_id,job_id
```

The output whit this query:

```
| msgType | user | job_id | project_id |
|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|
| 1       | 1    | 1      | 1          |
| 1       | 1    | 2      | 1          |
| 2       | 1    | 3      | 1          |
| 2       | 1    | 4      | 1          |
| 1       | 1    | 5      | 2          |
```

My desired output would be:

```
| msgType | user | job_id | project_id |
|++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++|
| 1       | 1    | 1      | 1          |
| 2       | 1    | 3      | 1          |
| 2       | 1    | 4      | 1          |
| 1       | 1    | 5      | 2          |
```

So basically `if msgType = 1` then i want to see 1 row for every user in every different project_id `if msgType=2` then i want to see every job_id in a "project"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

i created a fiddle for this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5708b8/4

Comment: @ManishVerma Thank you for your comment, no unfortunately because of the GROUP BY job_id it will not provide the desired output. Since i will see 2 rows when msgType = 1 because there are different job_ids

Comment: Why are you using "group by"? You have nothing to group (you are not using any aggregate functions, eg SUM())

Comment: Hey you edited the question after my comment. Can you please elaborate a little with more example rows.

Comment: Are you really missing 1 record on your desired output, particular job_id =2?

Comment: @AlvinCaseria that would be my desired output if msgType = 1 i don't interested in the job_ids else i do

Comment: @ManishVerma i made a sql fiddle updated my question

Comment: Do you have any other values for `msgType`? What are the possible values for all other columns?

Comment: @GaborSch For msgType the only values are 1 and 2 the other columns can be anything since those coming from other tables

Comment: @user1291203: I have changed your fiddle in my answer. Please check. For the given input, output as desired is obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT * FROM
   (
     SELECT msgType ,user, min(job_id), project_id 
     FROM mail
     WHERE msgType = 1
     GROUP BY msgType,user,project_id

     UNION ALL

     SELECT msgType ,user, job_id, project_id 
     FROM mail
     WHERE msgType <> 1

   )T ORDER BY T.msgType Desc
```

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5708b8/7

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   SELECT * FROM
   (
    SELECT msgType ,user, job_id, project_id 
    FROM mail
    WHERE msgType = 1
    GROUP BY msgType,user,project_id,job_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT msgType ,user, job_id, project_id 
    FROM mail
    WHERE msgType <> 1
   )T ORDER BY T.msgType Desc
```

Like **[Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian)** said, You can't use `Group BY` without using any `aggregate functions` in your case.

If you want to get the desired result then you have to use query like below but not exactly

```
   SELECT * FROM
   (
    SELECT msgType ,user, MIN(job_id), project_id
    FROM mail
    WHERE msgType = 1
    GROUP BY msgType,user, project_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT msgType ,user, job_id, project_id 
    FROM mail
    WHERE msgType <> 1
   )T ORDER BY T.msgType Desc
```

Comment: just a side note for OP, if you'd like to order the results in someway, you could try `(<first query from this answer>) UNION ALL (<second query>) order by msgType desc`

Comment: Thank you for your effort :) i made a little sql fiddle with your answer unfortunately its not returning the desired result :S http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5708b8/1

Answer (score 1):

To do it all in one statement you could do this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5708b8/16

```
SELECT msgType
, min(user) user
, min(job_id) job_id
, project_id
FROM mail
group by msgType
, project_id
, case when msgType = 1 then user else job_id end
```

Though I suspect the `union all` methods above are simpler to understand, so may be better from a maintainability perspective.